# FileType_en_US_default instead of PNG

Tags: file-association, png, file-types

I just noticed that Windows Explorer (in Windows 7) shows the PNG filetype as “FileType_en_US_default” instead of the normal “PNG file” or whatever it shows in my german localization with Adobe Fireworks as the default application.

Is there any way to restore that to the default without having to repair/reinstall Fireworks (and have that update the file association)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all that's messed up is the file type description, right? Do your `.png` files open with the proper program and have the proper context menu?

File type descriptions are easily changeable using [**Default Programs Editor**](http://defaultprogramseditor.com).

Open the program, click `File Type Settings` then `Description`

[image: Default Programs Editor, File Type Settings]

That will take you here:
[image: Using Default Programs Editor to change file type description]
Then put in whatever you want, "PNG Image file" or whatever and hit `Save`.

Comment: Thanks, although in the end I changed it via registry.